# Find global references to struct element using VIM

Tags: vim, linux-kernel

I'm working with the Linux Kernel, so I installed ctags and cscope to help me find references. However, there's no way to find references to `struct->element`.

Then, I installed coc.nvim and ccls to see if that would help, but I'm only getting local references to `struct->element`.

Is there a way to find global references to a struct element inside of VIM?

Comment: Can you provide some particular example in kernel? Like some particular struct, field, and local/global references?

Comment: I'm studying synchronization primitives in the Linux Kernel, and I chose a staging driver. So now I'm reading segments that are protected by these, let's say ieee->state (for a RTL driver). I need to check all accesses to this ieee->state in the code as local references aren't enough. I got all the references by using grep and a small script but it would be nice to have a list inside of VIM.

Comment: I don't think you can find struct field usage with `cscope` or `ctags`, sorry. It's either `grep` or some IDE like Eclipse + CDT.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably the quickfix list, which can be set using

- `:grep`
- `:vimgrep` (handy when you only want to search, say, files in the argument list `##`)
- any tool for which you can configure either the output to match the default quickfix pattern-matching, or vice-versa

In your case, I would either do

```
vim -q <(git grep '->element')
```

Or I would use the `git-jump` script in git’s contrib folder:

```
git jump grep '->element'
```

You could also load up certain files you care about with one of

```
vim my files...
```

or

```
:args my files...
```

And then search those with

```
:vimgrep /->element/ ##
```